# Points ranking system

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ranking

Below is the code I have to retrieve the rank of a certain images, everything works perfectly fine. However, if two or more images has the  same total points, I am getting duplicate rank results. My main goal is, if two or more images has tie total_points, rank them based on when these images were submitted. (old to recent order). How do I break the tie?

Comment: please undelete your query and table definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to rank by total points descending and date ascending:

```
set @rank = 0;
select @rank := @rank + 1 as rank,
  photo_id,
  total_points,
  date
from photo_list
order by
  total_points desc,
  date asc
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40079/9)**

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple query which orders by total points, and then by date?  This query will return the top ten results:

```
SELECT `id`
     , `photo_id`
     , `total_points`
     , `date`
  FROM `photos
 ORDER
    BY `total_points` DESC,
       `date` ASC
 LIMIT 10
     ;
```